# How can I add a payment gateway method to my chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I create a chrome extension and want to add a payment gateway method How can  I add a payment gateway method to my chrome extension

Answer (score 0):

Depends, What's your Chrome Extension based on?
If it's just a normal extension with a Donate Me button, You could use PayPal and link a button/image.
If it's a subscription based, You will have to link it to your website and set it up to send/receive messages and give the user access to the extension.

To know more about setting it up check:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#external-webpage

Comment: Yes, I want just donate me button like not a subscription based could you please send me some resources for this

Comment: Sure, I can help you with it.
You can set it up with PayPal, So first step would be setting up a PayPal payment link, Followed by editing the popup.html/index.html by adding a button/image that links to your PayPal page.